# How to change Spark Streaming application with checkpointing?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Please consider the following scenario:

- created initial pipeline via Spark streaming
- enable checkpointing
- run the application for a while
- stop streaming application
- made tiny changes to the pipeline, e.g. business logic remained untouched but did some refactoring, renaming, class moving, etc.
- restart the streaming application
- get an exception as pipeline stored in checkpoint directory differs on a class level from the new one

What are the best practices to deal with such a scenario? How can we seamlessly upgrade streaming application with checkpointing enabled? What are the best practices for versioning of streaming applications?

Comment: In order to upgrade seamlessly from one version of jar to another you need to handle the checkpointing yourself. In case of direct kafka api this can be done easily . Or else you have to clean your checkpoint directory for every upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 2 questions: 1st - do you have an example how to handle checkpointing yourself? At least using Kafka? My example is Twitter based, 2nd - After cleanup I will loose my previous aggregated state, so that is not an option for me.

Comment: My application is stateless and I needed checkpoint to start reading kafka offset from the point where it left in case of driver failure (jar upgrade needs driver restart). Instead of relying on checkpoint , I accessed the offsets and stored it to the external db. And during init I will restore the offsets from external db in streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Checkpointing is for recovery situations not for upgrades.

From the [official documentation about Checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing):

> A streaming application must operate 24/7 and hence must be resilient to failures unrelated to the application logic (e.g., system failures, JVM crashes, etc.). For this to be possible, Spark Streaming needs to checkpoint enough information to a fault- tolerant storage system such that it can recover from failures.

So to answer your question about using checkpointing (that is meant for fault tolerance) and changing your application code, you should not expect it would work since it is against the design.

Comment: Jacek, thank you for the answer, I read a documentation very carefully. Just would like to understand best practices. What you are saying right now means that if I make any changes to my pipelines, then we should not rely on checkpointing anymore, i.e. clear the directory and have other custom mechanisms to restore state, i.e. use other storage/own custom logic to restore from the latest state. Are we on the same page?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what it means. You need to have other means to have all state in sync w data storage before upgrade. No idea what it could be though.